# JavaScript/python communications on two different devices

Tags: javascript, python, api, flask

I have a python script that reads sensor data using pyserial and saves it on a .txt file. I have another python script that reads the data from a text file and puts it on an HTML page using Flask API. The HTML page is on a local network. I want to pass the sensor data from the HTML page to my User Interface code (.js) on another device. How can I make this communication possible?
Here is my Python code that uses flask API to put the sensor data on an HTML page

```
global data
data='0'
@app.route('/')
def index():
    with open('Sensor_Data_Storage.txt', 'rb') as File1: 
        line = File1.readline().decode()
    print(line)
    return render_template('sensor.html',dist=line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('192.168.0.110',8000)),app)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Keyboard interrupt received. Exiting.")
    finally:
        # clean up
        File1.close()
```

Here is my HTML page code (sensor.HTML)

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3 class="Tem">{{dist}}</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript code (the UI)

```
const sensorDataUrl = "http://192.168.0.110:8000";

function Sensor1Data() {
  const [sensorData, setSensorData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getSensorDataWithFetch();
  }, []);

  const getSensorDataWithFetch = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(sensorDataUrl);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    setSensorData(jsonData);
  };

  return(
    <div>
      <p> {sensorData.dist} </p>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Sensor1Data;
```

[Sensor Data on the HTML Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUEoJ.png)

Comment: let me get this straight ... that data goes from python -> HTML you've shown, and then from this HTML to the javascript you've shown?

Comment: yes. data goes from python -> HTML, and then from this HTML to the javascript shown

Comment: *"I want to pass the sensor data from the HTML page to my User Interface code (.js) on another device."* ... Will the "another device" be able to pull in the html on your network?

Comment: How does the data get into the HTML? seems unlikely, are you modifying the HTML with the data somehow?

Comment: All the devices will be on the same network; the device that is hosting the HTML page and the device that is hosting the UI will be on the same network.

Comment: My data is going to the HTML page through this line ``` return render_template('sensor.html',dist=line) ```

Comment: Since your "another device" can access the network to reach your "server", why not use a GET or POST request to get the data as opposed to parsing html?

Comment: I am not sure if I need to use GET or POST. I tried putting both in the code but it didn't work. I am not sure how to implement the GET and POST. Does it have to be included in the python code to the JS code?